# OpenLayers Strategies

Tags: openlayers-2, vector

Can we use the strategies `OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed` and `OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX` simulataneously on same vector layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strategies can be used together in OpenLayers, however, I'm not sure I can think of a use case that would combine the `OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed` and `OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX` strategies.

The `OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed` strategy is all about requesting data once and then never again. So you could use this strategy to grab data first when the map is constructed, for example using the `preLoad` option, so there is data ready to go when the map is ready. Be careful using this approach since data is loaded before features are drawn and so could slow down your map.

The `OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX` strategy is used to request data from a server-side source whenever the viewport is invalidated, for example on pan or zoom. So I believe this strategy would kick in and override the `OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed` strategy previously set. It is worth bearing in mind that this strategy will request data for the viewport bounds once the map is created, and therefore in effect performs the same thing as `OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed` in terms of initially loading data.

I guess you could use `OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed` to request data for an extent that is greater than your map's initial extent, which would give a bunch of data at the outset. Then `OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX` can be used to kick-in for areas outside the initial extents. However, I suspect this might not actually work because `OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX` would kick-in as soon as the map viewport is invalidated. In which case you would need to have an event handler for the layer to prevent the strategy if the viewport is still within the initial extents.

I would be interested to know what your particular use case is for these strategies combined.